# Does anyone have a good example of how to save a numpy array to file using the struct python module?

Tags: python, numpy, struct, save, pypy

I have been experimenting with the best way to save a numpy array to file whilst using pypy (this means that I can't use the obvious `numpy.save`, `numpy.savetxt` etc as they are not supported). I've tried using the Pickle module (which works with pypy) but Pickle will only let me save lists of data. Although I can use `array.tolist()`, this gets complicated when moving away from a 1D numpy array.

I know that the Struct module can be used to save and load numpy arrays but I have not idea how to approach the problem and there seems to be little information online.

Any helpful tips/tutorials would be very useful!

Comment: I'm confused. Why can you not use pickle with the Numpy arrays directly?

Comment: It gives an error... `TypeError: can't pickle ndarray objects`

Answer (score 0):

With struct you can dump or read a whole array of data pretty easily to disk, but you are going to have to figure out how to store metadata, i.e. number of items written, size of each item, shape of the array...

Say, for instance, your arrays are always made of uint32s. Given such an array `arr` you could write it as:

```
f = open(filename, 'wb')
f.write(struct.pack('I', arr.ndim))
f.write(struct.pack('I' * arr.ndim, *arr.shape))
size = reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, arr.shape)
f.write(struct.pack('I' * size, *arr.ravel()))
```

and you could read it as

```
f = open(filename, 'rb')
ndim = struct.unpack('I', f.read(4))[0]
shape = tuple(struct.unpack('I' * ndim, f.read(4 * ndim)))
size = reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, shape)
arr = np.array(struct.unpack('I' * size, f.read(4 * size)).reshape(shape)
```

You could come up with a more complicated scheme to code the data type, the endianess of the data...

Also, if they work in your system, using [numpy.fromfile](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html) and [numpy.tofile](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html) for the actual dumping of the whole array is very convenient.